# Convert a string with commas to double

Tags: c#, converters

I have a string like this: `99  365  25,633  gghddhdf  35`

I need all the numbers in an array. My problem is how do I handle `25,633`  because of the ','.  How I can get this number too? My code is:

```
public string campDiff(string lineStr1, string lineStr2)
{
    int size;
    string sum = null;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double number;

    string[] lineArr1 = lineStr1.Split(' '); ;
    string[] lineArr2 = lineStr2.Split(' ');

    if (lineArr1.Length > lineArr2.Length)
    {
        size = lineArr1.Length;
    }
    else
    {
        size = lineArr2.Length;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        if (Double.TryParse(lineArr1[i], out num1))
        {


            if (Double.TryParse(lineArr2[i], out num2))
            {

                number = num2 - num1;
                if (number > 0)
                {
                    sum = Convert.ToString(number);
                    return sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But it's skipping over the number with the commas.

Comment: I assume this starts with a String.Split on the space character?

Comment: yes this is the arry of lineArr1 and 2

Comment: Please show all relevant code, i.e. where you create the `lineArr`

Comment: Do you always get numbers with `,` as the thousand separator in your `lineArr`? Do you want to use the current locale to parse the double, or do you always want to use the invariant one where `,` separates thousands and never decimals.

Comment: Overall, comma and point conversion is a mess. Technically the proper way to do that is to go through the CultureInfo/IFormatProvider class and get the PC's locale settings. To make things more portable, though, you're much better off just replacing the symbol to the one you expect and then parsing it with InvariantCulture, which expects a `.`.

Comment: i edit the post to all functuon

Comment: @Nyerguds not sure what you mean by "go through" the class... you can just pass the `CultureInfo`/`IFormatProvider` - either the current or the invariant one - into `double.TryParse` and it will just use those settings.

Comment: dont return inside loop. also `size` should be equal to the array with less length. other wise out of bounds exception is possible.

Comment: On a totally different note. Who or what is giving you the input line(s)?  Probably it's another system. Who says it must be interpreted the way you are interpreting it? Should the value be interpreted as an int or as a double or decimal? The latter depends on which culture was used by the sender. Just a reminder, don't take csv files/format too lightly ;-)

Comment: @CompuChip Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Making use of that whole culture system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible solutions. Although, the best one I think is to set your `CultureInfo` to Invariant and then replace all commas with dots. For example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string number = "3,2";
double d = double.Parse(number.Replace(",", "."));
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

In your code that would be made like this:

```
    double[] numbers1 = 
        lineStr1.Replace(",", ".")
                    .Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s =>
                    {
                        double value;
                        bool success = double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);

                        return new { value, success };
                    })
                    .Where(p => p.success)
                    .Select(p => p.value)
                    .ToArray();

    double[] numbers2 = 
        lineStr2.Replace(",", ".")
                    .Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s =>
                    {
                        double value;
                        bool success = double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);

                        return new { value, success };
                    })
                    .Where(p => p.success)
                    .Select(p => p.value)
                    .ToArray();
```

Now you have two arrays ***numbers1 and numbers2*** with all possible numbers parsed from the two strings ***lineStr1 and lineStr2***. You decide what to do with them as I cannot understand fully the purpose of your method.

(*Thanks to all the guys in the comments for making me edit my answer.*)

Comment: I would suggest `number.Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".")` though... just to be sure!

Comment: And I would also pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` into the `TryParse` rather than change the current thread's locale. That may give nasty surprises later on.

Comment: also it is possible that `lineArr[i]` throws exception. because the counter goes up to size of larger array.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the comma should be a decimal point?  In OPs example, that would be a valid number as a comma. I don't think the general answer of just convert the comma to a decimal point is safe without knowing precisely what the source is providing.  Better to use the appropriate local culture or culture of the provider than force the invariant culture

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have *only* one string that contains `,` in your string, then you can split your string with white space, get the item contains that character, then parse it to `double` with a culture that has `,` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) like (`tr-TR`).

```
var str = "99 365 25,633 gghddhdf 35";
var element = str.Split(' ').Where(s => s.Contains(',')).ToArray()[0];

double d = double.Parse(element, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"));
```

I used `tr-TR` because it's my current culture. You can [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone.aspx) your `CurrentCulture` and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` property to `,` if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the current lineArrX IsLetter or not before doing the sub.

```
public class IsLetterSample {
public static void Main() {
    char ch = '8';

    Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLetter(ch));                   // False
    Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLetter("sample string", 7));   // True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could regex the string first

```
 Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);
```